# Dealing with NaN in BERT for Multi-class Text Classification of unlabelled text

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, cosine-similarity, multiclass-classification

I am just starting to explore Bert in a multiclass text classification task. In doing that, I am using this [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gulUflDeftjTB0oFV_A4_ahAjwcg7nQi/view?usp=sharing). This is my [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uhwL-qjFpFBPsCGWTM3C7XwYok7Bw70c/view?usp=sharing). During model testing, attempt to compute cosine similarities:

```
#--- Model Algorithm ---#
## compute cosine similarities
similarities = np.array(
            [metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(X, y).T.tolist()[0] 
             for y in dic_y.values()]
            ).T
```

gives this error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

From many stackoverflow posts, there were suggestions to eliminate `NaN` and null cells which I did at the beginning (see my [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uhwL-qjFpFBPsCGWTM3C7XwYok7Bw70c/view?usp=sharing)). There were also suggestions to replace `NaN` but I when I did as thus:

```
X = np.nan_to_num(X.astype(np.float32))
similarities = np.array(
                [metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(X, y).T.tolist()[0] 
                 for y in dic_y.values()]
                ).T
```

I got another error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Applying `.reshape(-1, 1)` or `.reshape(1, -1)` to `X`:

```
X = np.reshape(X, (-1, 1))
    similarities = np.array(
                    [metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(X, y).T.tolist()[0] 
                     for y in dic_y.values()]
                    ).T
```

generates the same error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I am sure that the input `X` is a 2D array and not 1D, because `X.ndim` is `2`. Any help will be appreciated.